# Xamarin Forms Navigation.PopAsync() for Master Detail Page

Tags: xamarin, navigation

I am currently developing a Xamarin Forms application which is using Master Detail Pages. I am able to push the master detail forms onto the Navigation Stack using Navigation.PushAsync(MasterDetailForm) but am not able to pop the master detail forms from the stack using Navigation.PopAsync(). I tried the Remove method but this didn't work either. I am wondering if anyone could help me please?

Comment: Why are you doing that exactly?

Comment: MasterDetail should be the root view of your app, not contained within a NavigationPage

Comment: I got the navigation working with Navigation.PushModelAsync and Navigation.PopModalAsync.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: `Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(MasterDetailForm))`? I think you dont have a root page. Or your Detail Page doesn't set as `Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(DetailPage))` or just simple Detail = DetailPage. Check this project: https://github.com/officialdoniald/Xamarin.Forms.CustomControls